# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) Python

Tags: python-3.8

here is the code:

```
import socket
import time

target = input("[+] Target ip:  ")
port = input("[+] Port:  ")
print("[+] Sending package to:   > " + target, "<")
time.sleep(1)

byte_message = bytes("Test", "utf-8")
opened_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
opened_socket.sendto(byte_message, (target ,port))
```

I get this error at line 12:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: There is no line 12. Provide the whole stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert port to int.

```py
try:
    port = int(input("[+] Port:  ")) # Maybe verify value of port is valid such as ensuring its not negative
except:
    # Specify what to do if port is not a number ie invalid
    print("Please specify valid input port")
```